# Rails 3.2 Dev environment sourceMaps support for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, source-maps

I am working on a Rails App using Asset pipeline. The development.rb has the following:

```
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.debug = true
```

In Dev environment, the assets are not bundled up and each is served up by Rails individually. At this point, the number of assets that are getting served individually are more than 50. Hence, full page reloads are extremely slow.

I would like to concatenate them atleast in a few assets for faster loading time on dev environment but doing that, I loose the ability to debug/see them individually in Chrome dev tools. Example: http://d.pr/i/ZFge

There are two ways to solve this in my knowledge, after you do:

```
  config.assets.debug = false
```

and start serving them as concatenated assets.

1. Old Hacky Way: @sourceUrl trick.
2. New Way: [sourceMaps](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps).

Is there a guide on how I can enable them on a rails app ? I dont use CoffeeScript so https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps is not helpful. Most Google Searches lead to that.

I am looking for a solution for native JS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't seen an existing solution for this problem. But building one will be quite straight forward.

The following assumes `gem uglifier` is the js compressor in use.

Version 2 of uglifier has a mechanism to create sourcemap. It has the following syntax

```
uglified, source_map = Uglifier.new.compile_with_map(source)
```

Rails asset pipeline allows to specify custom JS Compressor (with a `compress` method) using the following syntax

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Transformer.new
```

read about that [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#using-your-own-compressor)

A simple Transformer class would look like the following

```
class Transformer
  def compress(string)
    if Rails.env.development?
      output, sourcemap = Uglifier.new.compile_with_map(string)

      # write the sourcemap to a file somewhere under public

      sourcemap_comment = "//@ sourceMappingURL=#{sourcemap_path}}\n"

      return output + sourcemap_comment
    else
      Uglifier.compile(string)
    end
  end
end
```

**Note**: This is not full solution just explaining the concepts. You can build on this and add ways to make it more robust.

Comment: For resolution sake, I gave up trying to roll this in. It felt like too much mucking around a very critical part of the process of serving assets. Accidental mistake here would cause too much headache.

Its a pity there is still no official way to do this.